# Plotting graph using matplotlib and pandas following tutorial causes error

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, matplotlib

So I'm following the tutorial from scratch and faced with a problem. 
I'm trying to plot graph but something goes wrong

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from reader import df_final

crimes_count_date = df_final.pivot_table('ID', aggfunc=np.size, columns='Primary Type',
                                         index=df_final.index.date, fill_value=0)
crimes_count_date.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(crimes_count_date.index)
plot1 = crimes_count_date.rolling(365).sum().plot(figsize=(12, 30), subplots=True,
                                                 layout=(-1, 3), sharex=False, sharey=False)
plt.plot(plot1)
plt.show()
```

Well, `df_final` is final dataframe read from csv file

When I ran `print(type(plot1))` it says `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

And the error log says

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/trends.py", line 27, in 
>       plot_frequency_trends()
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/trends.py", line 21, in plot_frequency_trends
>       plt.plot(plot1)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3363, in plot
>       ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1867, in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1529, in plot
>       self.add_line(line)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1960, in add_line
>       self._update_line_limits(line)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1982, in _update_line_limits
>       path = line.get_path()
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 956, in get_path
>       self.recache()
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 657, in recache
>       y = _to_unmasked_float_array(yconv).ravel()
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py", line 2052, in _to_unmasked_float_array
>       return np.asarray(x, float)
>     File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: get rid of the `plt.plot(plot1)` line. It should work without it, and there's no need for it.

Comment: thanks again) it worked finally. But it's strange cause i've found previous solution here and it worked o.O

Comment: Well in this case, since you are using subplots, `s2` is an array of matplotlib_axes.